# Jquery can't find element after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to set a function on an element created after an ajax call (set by google api v3, clicking on a suggested search term on a search bar) but Jquery can't find it in the DOM.
A try a lot of thing with the `.on()` and `.live()` but I can't make them work.
I have spent more than 3 hours on this problem, so if someone have the solution, I would be very thankful.

[I set a jsfiddle of the exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/g3qda/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element is removed on click, so your click handler never fires as the `mouseup` event happens on another element. This means you have to use `mousedown`, and the elements are dynamic so you'll need to use `on()`

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.pac-container .pac-item', function() {
   alert('putainZZZZ');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/g3qda/1/)

Comment: OMG its's working ! Thank you very much, I'm kind of new with handling  ajax functionnalities.